# IEEE Citation Style, Title ends with a comma

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am writing a documentation for a study project. I'm using the `IEEEtran` style for citations. I've noticed that the titles of web documents (exported as `@misc` in the `.bib` file) always close with the comma first and then the quotation mark follows. I also found multiple examples online, for example this one: [image: https://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/ieee/internet]

Why is the comma in the title within the quotation marks and not outside, like this:

[#]A. Author, "Document title", Webpage name,...

Is this a mistake, or is there some kind of explanation?

Comment: It is common American style to "move" the following punctuation *inside* quotation marks. See e.g. https://www.unr.edu/writing-speaking-center/student-resources/writing-speaking-resources/british-american-english and https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/may/19/mind-your-language-punctuation-quotations.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a good explanation. Although that is really weird as an non native speaker. Do you want to put your answer as the answer, then i can accept it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common American style to move following punctuation *inside* quotation marks (even if "logically" one would expect it to go outside). See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Order_of_punctuation and the discussion at https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/may/19/mind-your-language-punctuation-quotations